# zmq in scala,no jzmq in java.library.path in eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, scala, sbt, zeromq, failed-installation

I got the error when run the Scala project with zmq as mentioned below,and i want to what is java.library.path?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jzmq in 
java.library.path
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
at org.zeromq.ZMQ.<clinit>(ZMQ.java:37)
at 
org.arpit.scala.training.day1.FunctionalStyle$.main(FunctionalStyle.scala:8)
at org.arpit.scala.training.day1.FunctionalStyle.main(FunctionalStyle.scala)
```

my code was given below,

```
import org.zeromq.ZMQ
object FunctionalStyle {

def main(args : Array[String]) {

    val context = ZMQ.context(1)
    val publisher = context.socket(ZMQ.PUB)
    println("hello")

    val sync = context.socket(ZMQ.PULL)

    sync.bind("tcp://localhost:5564")

    // We send updates via this socket
    publisher.bind("tcp://localhost:5565")
    publisher setHWM 2

    sync recv 0


    for (i <- 1 to 10) {
        val msg = String.format("Update %d", i: Integer)
        publisher.send(msg.getBytes(), 0)
        Thread sleep 1000
    }
    publisher.send("END".getBytes(), 0)
    Thread sleep 1000 
}
}
```

Here give the build.sbt file is given below,

```
import Dependencies._
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
settings(
inThisBuild(List(
  organization := "com.example",
  scalaVersion := "2.12.3",
  version      := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
)),
name := "Hello",
libraryDependencies += scalaTest % Test
)

libraryDependencies += "org.zeromq" % "jzmq" % "2.1.2"
```

How to rectify this error ,please give any suggestions?

Comment: You tag your question as `sbt`, and then show nothing of the `.sbt`. Is [this dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.zeromq/jzmq/3.1.0) in your `build.sbt`?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin,I only add the zmq dependency in build.sbt,Thanks Andrey Tyukin your fast response

Answer (score 1):

### Before going anywhere deeper in the code, best test installed version first:

If the version reports correctly, your installation is configured well enough to proceed further, if not, the issue is not with the ZeroMQ or any code per-se, but with either the failed installation or mis-configuration of tools.

```
/*
*
* Version in Scala
*
* @author Vadim Shalts
* @email vshalts@gmail.com
*/

import org.zeromq.ZMQ

object version {

  def main( args: Array[String] ) {
    printf( "INF: ZMQ-Version string: %s\n",
                  ZMQ.getVersionString
             )
    printf( "INF: ZMQ-Version int: %d\n"
                  ZMQ.getFullVersion
             )
  }
}
```

If this does not compile / run smooth, the root cause is in the installation and/or configuration of tools.

After these both report matching the desired Major#-Minor#-Patch# numbers, both your installation and configuration is ready and fit to produce any further ZeroMQ tools for your scala-Projects correctly.

Comment: As expressed in the answer, **if even this does not work, the installation + IDE confguration does not meet and fail to generate a fully functional executable**. ZeroMQ is out of the game, revise and redo the installation process and the IDE configuration. No other way forwards.